# Passing values from Excel to Word with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
For Each cell In rng
    workSheetName = Format(SaturdayIsComing(), "mm-dd-yyyy") & " " & cell.Value
    If WorksheetExists(workSheetName) Then
        Dim localRange, localCell As Range
        Set localRange = Worksheets(workSheetName).Range("D8:D19")
        Dim contents As Variant
        contents = ""
        Dim firstLine As Boolean
        firstLine = True
        For Each localCell In localRange
            If Len(localCell.Value) > 0 Then
                If firstLine Then
                    contents = contents & localCell.Value & Chr(11)
                Else
                    contents = contents & Chr(9) & Chr(9) & Chr(9) & localCell.Value & Chr(11)
                End If
            Else
                contents = fixString(contents)
            End If
            If Len(contents) > 0 Then
                firstLine = False
            End If
        Next localCell

        For Each cc In wDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag(cell.Value & "Notes")
            If Len(contents) > 0 Then
                cc.Range.Text = fixString(contents)
            Else
                cc.Range.Text = "No Issues Found"
            End If
        Next
    Else
        errorCodesString = errorCodesString & cell.Value & ":"
    End If
Next cell
```

Output to Word

```
 Forgot to terminate the meeting
 This is a test message\'s
```

If my cell contains a **'** then I get an error saying

```
One of the values passwed to this method or property is incorrect
```

I know a ' is a comment in VBA. How do I go around this while preserving the notes that someone had added to the Excel cell?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a piece of code to search for quotes, either the single (') or double (") variety and either add a backslash before them OR double the character so '' in place of ' and "" in place of " and run this on contents before assigning it to cc.Range.Text.

This routine can also check for other instances of incorrect strings and fix them.

Something like this would do:

```
Function fixString(ByVal strIn As Variant) As String
Dim i As Integer

Const strIllegals = "\'"""
For i = 1 To Len(strIllegals)
strIn = Replace(strIn, Mid$(strIllegals, i, 1), "\" & Mid$(strIllegals, i, 1))
Next i
fixString = strIn
End Function
```

[image: Conversion Picture]

Comment: I get a ByRef argument type mismatch

Comment: is contents defined as a string?

Comment: its defined as a Variant

Comment: The issue is trying to convert the Variant into a string when it is not a legal string. So if you use the replacement function, which treats the input as a Variant and changes it to a string at the end, it should work.

Comment: I tried it but the value of contents turned into I\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ and the original value in the Excel cell was I'm happy to be here

Comment: I forgot that parameters are passed ByRef as default, thus causing all sorts of issues!

Comment: It was a good attempt but it's adding \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ to my string.

Comment: I'm trying in in Excel and it's working fine are you running the VBA in Excel before you send it to Word or in Word after it is received?

Comment: I am running the VBA from within Excel and it's being outputted to a Word file.

Comment: Do you still get the error if you comment out the line cc.Range.Text = contents

Comment: Sorry there is no error message. It does execute the method but the actual contents in the word file appears as "I\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\...\\m happy you\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\...\\re here"

Comment: Could you show more code so I can copy it into excel and test it as it is working for me do something else must be happening.

Comment: Resolved it with Replace(contents, "'", Chr(39)). Maybe you can incorporate the Chr(39) with your function

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `cell.Value` to `Replace(cell.Value, "'", "")`

Or is it contents that has the apostrophe in it? A bit confusing.

Try changing `contents` to `Replace(contents , "'", "")`

Comment: The content may contain ' and other punctuation marks. The user can type anything on the keyboard like #1 the rain in spain.... or My favorite's

Comment: your solution is to remove the ' (apostrophe) from the string. Is there no way to keep it?